# Hashing structures in C

Tags: c, pointers, hash, struct

So I'm attempting to implement a hash table that will hash structures containing words.

the structures will be similar to this:

```
#ifndef HASHTABLE_H
#def HASHTABLE_H

typedef int (*HashFunctionT) (char* string, int upperbound);

struct node_
{
    char * word;
    struct node * next;
}
typedef struct node_ * node;

struct nodehash_
{
    int size;
    struct node * hash[100];
}
typedef struct nodehash_ * nodehash;

Hashtable createHashTable();
void addtohash(node list, nodehash hash);
#endif
```

And I want the hash function to work something like this:

```
#include "hashtable.h"

int hashFunction(char *word, int hashTableSize)
{
    int length = strlen(word);
    int h = 0;
    int i;  
    for(i = 0; i<length; i++)
    {
        h=31 *h  + word[i];
    }
    return h % hashTableSize;
};

nodehash createHashtable()
{
    nodehash hashtable;    
    hashtable = malloc(sizeof(struct nodehash_));

    hashtable->size = 100;
    hashtable->hash = malloc(100 * sizeof (node));
    int i;   
    for (i = 0; i < hashtable->size; i++)
    {
            hashtable->table[i] = NULL;
    }
    return hashtable;
};

void addtohash(node list, nodehash hashtable)
{
    int nodehashnumber;
    nodehashnumber = hashfunction(list->word, hash->size);
    hashtable->hash[nodehasnumber] = list;
};
```

And the main functio will look something like this (assume that the linked list of node structures has been created and filled).

```
int main()
{
    nodehash hashtable = createhashtable();
    node nodelist;
    /* here the nodelist would be created and filled and such and such*/
    while (nodelist->next != NULL)
    {
        addtohash(nodelist, hashtable);
    }
    return;
}
```

Assume that there can be no collisions, because every word to be hashed will be different.

BAsically, I'm wondering if I missed and glaring, obvious mistakes or flaws in logic.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Would this be better at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Oh I didn't even know that existed... thanks for letting me know!

Comment: You cannot really assume there can be no collisions just because each word is different.  Your hash function can produce the same output for multiple different inputs.

Comment: Also, if you were to assume no collisions, then why are you using a node struct with a next pointer?  You could just use an array of char* if not accounting for collisions

Comment: So this is all part of a larger project implementing an LRU cache... basically, we are given a .txt file as input, and we need to tokenize the file, and search through the file using something better than O(n^2) time (so basically, linear search is out of the question, and we are encouraged to use a hashtable). The LRU cache is to contain the tokens, and will be dynamic: that is to say, the user specifies their own cache size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't give the code an extensive read, but the first thing that stood out pretty clearly is the hash table size, `100`. It is best to use a [prime number for the size of your hash tables](https://planetmath.org/GoodHashTablePrimes) to help avoid collisions.

Comment: That and the fact that it's a magic number that appears in several places.

Comment: @FredLarson: No wonder it stood out so quickly :) -- gfppaste, definitely replace the hardcoded `100` with a variable or `#define`, so you can more easily change the size of your tables in the future.

Comment: I don't think that prime numbers perform necessarily better in this case. Given enough spread (the K&R hash mentioned in not the best in town, but will do for reasonable length strings), the modulo 100 will not perform _much_ worse than a modulo 101.

Comment: And given that there's apparently no chance of input collisions, it doesn't really matter anyhow. :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a problem with semicolons:

```
struct node_
{
    char * word;
    struct node * next;
}   /* <<-- HERE */
typedef struct node_ * node;
```

But::

```
int hashFunction(char *word, int hashTableSize)
{
    int length = strlen(word);
    int h = 0;
    int i;  
    for(i = 0; i<length; i++)
    {
        h=31 *h  + word[i];
    }
    return h % hashTableSize;
}; /* <<-- NOT here */
```

Also, a wise advice is IMHO to use as many *unsigned* types as possible: for the hash value (what does modulo division do with a negative operand?) and for sizes and indexes.

Rule of thumb: **if it can not be negative: it's unsigned**.